# Why does my CSS require some extra useless code to run

Tags: html, css

So I am making a simple user input form using HTML and CSS. I found a good CSS form design online and decided to adapt it to my form. As I was removing some unnecessary classes, selectors from the CSS that are not required for my HTML page I noticed that the CSS was not getting applied on my Submit button. If i keep the extra class even if it is empty the button's CSS gets applied but if I completely remove it then the button CSS fails?.

The original code from the website where I got the CSS can be found here, the form style 5 is used: [Form Style 5](https://www.sanwebe.com/2014/08/css-html-forms-designs)

```css
div{
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
}

form{
    display: inline-block;
}
.form-style-5{
    max-width: 250px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.form-style-5 fieldset{
    max-width: 500px;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    padding: 0;
    background: #f4f7f8;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-family: Georgia,"Times New Roman",Times,serif;
    border: none;
}
.form-style-5 legend {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #717171;
    border: 0;
}
.form-style-5 label {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}


.form-style-5 input[type="text"],
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]{
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 7px;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    background-color: #e8eeef;
    color:#8a97a0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.03) inset;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

}
.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,
.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus
{
    background: #d2d9dd;
    /*outline: none;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;*/
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}
.form-style-5 select{
    /*Removing this name selector causes the below button class selector CSS to not be applied?*/
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"],
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    padding: 19px 39px 18px 39px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1abc9c;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: normal;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #16a085;
    border-width: 1px 1px 3px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-style-5 input[type="submit"]:hover,
.form-style-5 input[type="button"]:hover
{
    background: #109177;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="UserInput_CSS.css">

 <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
    alert("I am called");
    var fname = document.myForm.fname.value;
    var lname = document.myForm.lname.value;
    var age = document.myForm.age.value;
    //var expr = new RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/g);
    var expr = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/m;

    if(fname == "" || !isNaN(fname) || !expr.test(fname)) // || fname == NULL || fname== "(null)", !fname.match(expr)   
    {
        alert( "Please enter proper First Name" );
            document.myForm.fname.focus() ;
            return false;
    }

    if(lname == "" || !isNaN(lname) || !expr.test(lname)) // || lname == NULL || lname== "(null)", !lname.match(expr), !/^[a-zA-Z]+$/g.test(lname), !expr.test(lname)
    {
        alert( "Please enter proper Last Name" );
            document.myForm.lname.focus() ;
            return false;
    }

    if(age == "" || age == 0 || age<0 || age >122 || isNaN(age))
    {
        alert( "Please enter proper Age" );
            document.myForm.age.focus() ;
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="form-style-5">
<form name="myForm" action="/itrade/user/CGI_Test.exe?action=submt" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();"> <!--onsubmit="return validateForm()"-->
<fieldset>
<legend>Candidate Info</legend>
First Name: <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name *"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name *"><br>
Age: <input type="text" name="age" placeholder="Age *"><br>
<input type="submit" value="submit"> <!--onclick = "return validateForm();"-->
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to make a plunkr to demonstrate your problem. Dumping a bunch of CSS on us and expecting us to dig through it is not the way to get help. https://plnkr.co/edit/

Comment: This is due to the extra closing `}` in `.form-style-5 input[type="text"]:focus,.form-style-5 input[type="number"]:focus`. Going to vote to close the question as a typographical error.

Comment: Your CSS has extra closing braces (look at the section right above `.form-style-5 select`).  Is that intentional or a copy paste error?

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes, Becuzz you gus are right in fact it wasn't just the extra bracket all the 5,6 lines above it were junk that I didn't delete properly. This has been such a stupid rookie mistake. Is there any way I can mark this question as solved or just delete it so, that I don't get burried in more down votes.

Comment: @Mike Chamberlain thank you for letting me know about plunker.

Comment: @user258365 Don't worry about it, we all have instances where all we need are another pair of eyes to spot something we've missed. Not sure what actions you have available to you at your rep but I would have thought that you should be able to delete the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax is incorrect as you have a closing brace without an opening brace or identifier located here:

```
    background: #1abc9c;
    color: #fff;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    margin-right: 4px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 0px;
}
```

Removing the empty style (which was helping to 'un-break' the CSS) caused your next style for the buttons to break.

Comment: beat me to it :)